# When I join a map of an object I get [object, Object]

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to join a map with a comma, like the following. It works fine without the join, however when I add the join on, I just get **[object Object] , [object Object] , [object Object]**.

What am I doing wrong? I suspect it's something really simple.

```
{artist?.genres &&
                  artist?.genres.map((genre) => {
                    return (
                      <Box key={genre.id} cursor={"pointer"} role={"group"}>
                        <HStack spacing={1}>
                          <Text
                            textTransform={"uppercase"}
                            fontSize={"lg"}
                          >
                            {genre.name}
                          </Text>
                        </HStack>
                      </Box>
                    );
                  }).join(" , ")}
```

Comment: Don't call `join`.

Comment: Why are you trying to `join`? What are you hoping it will achieve?

Comment: Oh I want to split my {genre.names} with a comma

Comment: That join will only concatenate the result of the map funciton, that are objects right now, and casting object to string results in "[object Object]". If you want to concatenate the genre.names, do another different map function returning only genre.names